# Reading list data like a loop

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Let's assume, I have a data set like:

```
data1 = {{{a1, b1, c1}, {d1, e1, f1}}, {{a2, b2, c2}, {d2, e2, f2}}, ..., 
         {{a20, b20, c20}, {d20, e20, f20}}}.
```

This can be seen as:

```
data1 = {X1, X2, ..., X20}. where Xi = {{ai, bi, ci}, {di, ei, fi}}
```

Now I want to use each`Xi`and perform an operation `R` (lets say R is a Matrix) on that.

How can I do that?

Comment: You actually *don't* want to do that in a loop. Instead, you want to `Map` a function over `data1`, Try `Map[func, data1]` to see what the result would look like. Besides, isn't this a very similar question to [your previous one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174981/27951)?

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your comment. Maybe I did not explain the problem properly before. Please have a look at the updated one and suggest if you feel.

Comment: Isn't this question very similar to [your other one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174981/choosing-data-sequentially-from-two-data-sets)?

Comment: Yes, I agree..and trying to solve the problem..

Comment: What is the dimension (or say shape) of `R`?

Comment: It's a (3X3) Matrix..

Comment: @Bikash Do you mean to do a group of (2x3).(3x3) matrix multiplications to get (2x3)s: `{X1.R, X2.R, ..., X20.R}`?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: @Bikash See my answer.

Comment: @ Αλέξανδρος thank you very much. It really helps !!

Comment: @Bikash Glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` (shorthanded as `/@`; this function is one of the typical that help one avoid explicit loops):

```
#.R & /@ data1
```

However, the best might be just using `Dot` (`.`):

```
data1.R
```

As a check, one can run codes below:

```
data1 = RandomInteger[10, {20, 2, 3}];
R = RandomInteger[10, {3, 3}];
#.R & /@ data1 == data1.R
```

which returns `True`.

Answer (score 4):

You really only need `Map` (`/@` as binary operator) and, in many cases, a custom function expressing what you want to do with each of sublists at level 1. Mathematica's ability to match argument patterns with the data given to a function will take care to the rest.

Here are the most common use-cases.

Function works directly on the sublists at level 1.

```
data =
  {{{a1, b1, c1}, {d1, e1, f1}},
   {{a2, b2, c2}, {d2, e2, f2}},
   {{a20, b20, c20}, {d20, e20, f20}}};

Transpose /@ data
```

> ```
> {{{a1, d1}, {b1, e1}, {c1, f1}}, 
>  {{a2, d2}, {b2, e2}, {c2, f2}}, 
>  {{a20, d20}, {b20, e20}, {c20, f20}}}
> ```

Function works directly on the two lists contained in the sublists at level 1.

```
f[{l1_List, l2_List}] := l1^l2
f /@ data
```

> ```
> {{a1^d1, b1^e1, c1^f1}, {a2^d2, b2^e2, c2^f2}, {a20^d20, b20^e20, c20^f20}}
> ```

Function works directly on the elements of the two lists contained in the sublists at level 1.

```
g[{{a_, b_, c_}, {d_, e_, f_}}] := d Sin[a] + e Cos[b] + f Tan[c]
g /@ data
```

> ```
> {e1 Cos[b1] + d1 Sin[a1] + f1 Tan[c1], 
>  e2 Cos[b2] + d2 Sin[a2] + f2 Tan[c2], 
>  e20 Cos[b20] + d20 Sin[a20] + f20 Tan[c20]}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to iterate through a list of data, one element at a time, you can use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) or [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html), depending on whether you want to collect the results for each element or just do something for each.

```
In[67]:= data = {a, b, c};

In[68]:= Table[ E^x, {x, data}]

Out[68]= {E^a, E^b, E^c}

In[69]:= Do[Print[x] , {x, data}]

During evaluation of In[69]:= a

During evaluation of In[69]:= b

During evaluation of In[69]:= c
```